# How to get parent id on Android?

Tags: android

I've tried to get parent id of RadioButton (id of RadioGroup) by

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) arg0.getParent();
```

but it failed. Following construction

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogr);
```

works well. How can I get parent id at runtime?

fails with these logs:

```
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at com.letmedraw.shopcart.ShopCartActivity.onCheckedChanged(ShopCartActivity.java:96)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:172)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:52)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:342)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:127)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:86)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:69)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-26 17:11:05.205: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why does it fail? ClassCastException?

Comment: Adding failure message (exception message) to the question will help in getting most accurate answer.

Comment: That does `arg0.getparent().getClass().getName()` yield?

Comment: What is arg0? Is it a RadioButton? Where are you declaring it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All views (controls) in android are of type `View`, so you can use `getId()` to find the id.

```
int parentId = ((View) arg0.getParent()).getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because getParent() is not RadioGroup value, and not an id either. getParent() returns ViewParent type, not a View.

ViewParent is interface and View is a class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems arg0 parent is LinearLayout, not Radio group and you are trying it to cast it as RadioGroup that is why it is throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just to more clarify the accepted answer, You can get parent Id (in integer form) of view any view, Like this

```
int parentId = ((View) arg0.getParent()).getId();
```

And now you can compare id with `R.id` to take your action. Because ids of all views are saved in `R file` in Android in integer format.

```
if (parentId == R.id.your_id) { //
     // Do whatever you want
}
```